# MySQL GROUP BY NULL and EMPTY

Tags: mysql, null, group-by

In a MySQL query I am doing a `GROUP BY` with a text field.  Due to the nature of the original data, some rows are contain empty strings for this field, and others are true `null`.

When grouping, how can I group empty string and null together, treating both as `null`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accomplished by SELECT CASE. There may be a simpler way I do not know of.

The format of SELECT CASE is

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN table_name.text_field IS NULL OR table_name.text_field = ''
    THEN null
    ELSE table.text_field
END as new_field_name,
other_field, another_field, ...rest of query...
```

So you see, you can CASE together values with WHEN/THEN and default to the real value by ELSE.