# Criteria builder grouping null and empty strings together

Tags: java, jdbc, criteria-api

I want to create sql query with criteria builder when I will group by some text field. The case is I want to group by fields with null values and empty strings together (I know that there is a difference between null and empty string but that's how it's already done and logically there is no difference). It's sth like here [MySQL GROUP BY NULL and EMPTY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577298/mysql-group-by-null-and-empty) but I want to do it in criteria builder and that's where is problem. I couldn't make coalesce work with builder.coalesce(entity.get("value"), "") or with builder.literal("") replacing "" like in the example:

```
public void groupBy(Path path){
    Expression group = builder.coalesce(entity.get("value"), ""); this doesn't work
    Expression<String> empty = builder.literal("");
    group = builder.coalesce(entity.get("value"), empty); this doesn't work either
```

The case is that writing it like this when hibernate query is created there are ?? in query and hibernate isn't sure whether they are the same value. I'm using that expression in both SELECT and GROUP BY and I get ERROR: value must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Is there any way to do this in criteria builder like creating some constant empty string value which will be translated to sql as '' rather than ? or some other way of grouping null values and empty strings together.

I'm using PostgreSQL, Hibernate, Java.

I will be grateful for every answer

Comment: The SQL-level technique is to group by an expression, eg in PostgreSQL you could `GROUP BY COALESCE(value,'')`

Comment: That I know but unfortunately I don't know how to make criteria builder do that in such a way that it would convert it to `GROUP BY coalesce (value, '')` rather than `GROUP BY coalesce (value, ?)`

Comment: Good point - and if you use a placement parameter, you'll have two different parameters `$1` and `$2` in the query that Pg won't know are the same until after planning time so it'll probably reject the query. `builder.literal("")` should work, though; what's wrong with that?  Please show the generated SQL query and exact error message text for that case.

Comment: _ERROR: column "value" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function_  - that's the error the same case as with simple ""

`select  coalesce(value, ?) ........ group by coalesce(value, ?) `
for the code `builder.coalesce(entity.get("value", builder.literal("")`
The same result unfortunately

Comment: Argh, so the criteria builder is using placement parameters for literals. You'll probably have to do this with a native query.

Comment: Looks like. Well thanks for concern

Comment: you can use  builder.sum(builder.literal(1)) to count null records, then post process null and empty string  records together in application